# Open ball around a point in the hyperplane in a locally convex space

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Let $f$ be a continuous linear functional in a locally convex space $X$ and let $z\in X$ so that $f(z)=\alpha$. Let $V_z$ be an open neighborhood around $z$.

It is my intuition that $V_z$ should contain points on both sides of the hyperplane, but I don't know exactly how to prove this or even if I am correct. That is, I want to show that there exists $x,y\in V_z$ so that $f(x)<\alpha$ and $f(y)>\alpha$.

Is my intuition correct, if so, is there a source that someone could point me to or a quick argument as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose wlog $z = 0$. If $f$ isn't zero, there is some $x\in V_0$ (wlog symmetric) with $f(x)\ne 0$. Take now $y = -x$.

Comment: Simple and clear. Thank you :)